# Difference between webSite testing and end-to-end testing

Tags: selenium, testing, cucumber, end-to-end

I would like to know the difference between end-to-end and website test in java web application,If we are testing the features of an website then it could be stated as end-to-end test right?

My second question is if i want to do end-to-end test which the best tool ?
selenium or cucumber ?
I am not able to conclude my self which tool to use.My requirement is as follows 
1)Test webapplication automatically by giving the required fields,and also it should interact with my service and database for retrieving information  in my UI.
Please help me.I am sorry if its a stupid question !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering all of your questions one by one :

- **`End-To-End Testing`** : `End-to-End Testing` is a testing methodology which is used to validate whether the flow of an application is performing as designed from start to finish.
- **`Website Testing`** : `Web Testing` is the name given to the software testing methodology that focuses on web applications. Website Testing can be catagorized as `Basic Functionality Testing` of the site, `Security Aspects` of the Web Application, `Accessibility` to intended users and `Performance Aspects` as well.
- **`Best Automation Tool for End-To-End Testing`** : Each and every automation tool have its advantages and disadvantages. **`Selenium-Cucumber`** is one of the widely used combination for Behavior Driven Development (`BDD`). But as a pure `End-To-End` Automation candidate **`Protractor`** is widely used.
- Overall using **`Selenium`** you can perform `Web Application Testing` by giving the required fields and also interact with the `services` and `data` retrieved from `database` on your `UI`.

Comment: I have one more doubt can we use cucumber test alone for end-to-end test?Is it preferred to use?

Answer (score 1):

You're quesiton will probably be removed from here since it doesn't fit the standards stack overflow requires but here's an answer in case it sticks around.

End to end testing concerns program flow from start to finish. If you have a system that is solely a website then they could be considered equivalent. If your project has a website and runs batch processes in the background, sends emails, etc. based on data entered into the website or actions users of the site take, then they're not really equivalent because testing your website isn't going to test that the mail server is configured properly or that your nightly batch runs properly.

There is no single tool to handle end to end testing. At best you'll have an amalgamation of various tools to handle testing but more than likely there will be some manual testing involved - it's all going to depend on your application.

You could for example: script selenium to enter orders into a site, then have a scheduled console application run overnight that verifies the end of day accounting handles the orders properly, you would manually check outlook to verify you received your order confirmation, and then come up with a way to verify the orders get sent to the fulfillment system.

As you can see by the example for that use case you're unlikely to find a general purpose tool that can handle all of that out of the box.